# execute a bash in C program to export environment variable

Tags: c++, bash, export, environment-variables, system

hello I’m trying to execute a bash file which has export inside, and this into my Cpp program.

The goal is to set my needed environment variable automatically at the start of one of my program.

I can't seem to make it work.

piece of my myExport.sh:

```
export LOG4CXXCONFFILE="/home/me/workspace/Log/log4cxx.properties"
```

my code is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << system(" bash myExport.sh");
    try
    {
        QString myFile = getenv("LOG4CXXCONFFILE");
        qDebug() << "my env variable directory path:"<< myFile;
    }
    catch(Exception&)
    {
        result = "EXIT_FAILURE";
    }
return a.exec();
}
```

my debug show me it worked but I can't get the env. variable:

> 0
>   my env variable directory path: ""

I thought it was maybe becauseThe scripts only sets the environment inside the subshell it runs in, so i tried:

`qDebug() << system(". ./myExport.sh")`;

which got me the same answer.

so I also tried :

```
qDebug() << system("source myExport.sh");
```

and the answer was:

```
sh: 1: source: not found
32512 
my env variable directory path: ""
```

i tryied :

> ```
> qDebug() << system("bash source myExport.sh");
> ```

```
bash: source: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type   (no file or directory of this type, don't know why this is the only error in french)
32512 
my env variable directory path: ""
```

I'm running out of idea, anybody know why it's not working please?

Comment: Smells of an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201677). Can you specify what you're actually trying to do (the bit about environment variables is not too clear), rather than delve into the details of launching `bash`?

Comment: This is a mess. You could at least have bothered to use capital letters and proper punctuation!

Comment: Why not go after the environment variables directly through API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I fully understand your question, but it seems to me that you're trying to update the environment of your process through a `bash` script. That's simply not possible. A child process can *never* modify the environment of its parent process.

And your application's process is *not* `bash` (it's your application), so it cannot "source" a shell script. If you have an environment-setup `bash` script, you have these options:

1. Run the env-setup script before you launch your application (perhaps launching your application through a wrapper `bash` script).
2. Execute `bash` as a child process, have it source the script and retrieve the relevant info out from it (such as writing the environment to standard output in the `bash` script and capturing its standard output in C++). For this, you might want to look at [`QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html), especially at [`QProcess::setReadChannel()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setReadChannel).